# How to make an input type=button act like a hyperlink and redirect using a get request?

Tags: html, button

How do I make a `<input type=button>` act like a hyperlink and redirect using a `GET` request?

Answer (score 185):

You can make `<button>` tag to do action like this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/">
   <button>Visit Google</button>
</a>
```

or:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/">
   <input type="button" value="Visit Google" />
</a>
```

It's simple and no javascript required!

---

> **NOTE:**
>
> This approach is not valid from HTML structure. But, it works on many modern browser. See following reference :
>
> - [For `<button>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/button.submit.html#button.submit-constraints); and
> - [For `<input type="button />`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.button.html#input.button-constraints)

Comment: How is this NOT the answer to this question? Perfect.

Comment: Because ["The interactive element `button` must not appear as a descendant of the `a` element."](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/button.submit.html#button.submit-constraints). However, it works well with most browsers.

Comment: @YaK And an <input type=button/> ?

Comment: @MaëlNison `<input type="button">` is essentially an `input` element. So, yes.

Comment: @YaK Thanks for validation info. I have updated the post and give a note on my answer.

Comment: @MaëlNison I was wrong, it appears that "[The interactive element `input` must not appear as a descendant of the `a` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.button.html#input.button-constraints)" either. So, no :).

Comment: @YaK Okay, I will add the validation reference for `input type=button` too. Thanks for your input, friend!

Comment: This added an unwanted underline, so I had to use `text-decoration: none;`. Great solution, aside from that.

Comment: bypass the input:  <a href="http://www.google.com" class="btn btn-danger">Google</a>

Comment: This is not acceptable any more according to w3c the element input must not appear as a descendant of the a element. https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Comment: does href and button type technically perform a GET request?

Comment: The links are broken @WayanWiprayoga

Comment: There is no mention of *"input must not appear as a descendant of the a element"* in the modern [HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html), so I guess not this is valid.

Answer (score 155):

There are several different ways to do that -- first, simply put it inside a form that points to where you want it to go:

```
<form action="/my/link/location" method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="Go to my link location" 
         name="Submit" id="frm1_submit" />
</form>
```

This has the advantage of working even without javascript turned on.

Second, use a stand-alone button with javascript:

```
<input type="submit" value="Go to my link location" 
    onclick="window.location='/my/link/location';" />
```

This however, will fail in browsers without JavaScript (Note: this is **really** bad practice -- you should be using event handlers, not inline code like this -- this is just the simplest way of illustrating the kind of thing I'm talking about.)

The third option is to style an actual link like a button:

```
<style type="text/css">
.my_content_container a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #777777;
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
    border-right: 1px solid #333333;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    height: 2.5em;
    padding: 0 1em;
    width: 5em;       
    text-decoration: none;       
}
// :hover and :active styles left as an exercise for the reader.
</style>

<div class="my_content_container">
    <a href="/my/link/location/">Go to my link location</a>
</div>
```

This has the advantage of working everywhere **and** meaning what you most likely want it to mean.

Comment: Why is it bad practice? Just 2% (USA) of users have Javascript disabled: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478737/browser-statistics-on-javascript-disabled.

Comment: The "really bad practice" comment was in regards to my inline `onclick` handler - that said, you can't right-click on that button and open it in a new window regardless of whether you have JS enabled, so I'd prefer the `a` tag solution anyway.  Everyone is [at least situationally disabled](https://twitter.com/howiemeg/status/730152631562207232) at some point in their lives

Comment: Your solution works, just want to confirm if I need to put '/' at the end of the tag.

Answer (score 7):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
function newPage(num) {
var url=new Array();
url[0]="http://www.htmlforums.com";
url[1]="http://www.codingforums.com.";
url[2]="http://www.w3schools.com";
url[3]="http://www.webmasterworld.com";
window.location=url[num];``
}
// -->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#">
<div id="container">
<input class="butts" type="button" value="htmlforums" onclick="newPage(0)"/>
<input class="butts" type="button" value="codingforums" onclick="newPage(1)"/>
<input class="butts" type="button" value="w3schools" onclick="newPage(2)"/>
<input class="butts" type="button" value="webmasterworld" onclick="newPage(3)"/>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

Here's the other way, it's simpler than the other one.

```
<input id="inp" type="button" value="Home Page" onclick="location.href='AdminPage.jsp';" />
```

It's simpler.

Comment: a bit too complicated for a simple example, but factually correct. Welcome to SO.

Comment: <input id="inp" type="button" value="Home Page" onclick="location.href='AdminPage.jsp';" />

Comment: better :) now edit your post to include that as well - I think I just upvoted you enough to edit your own posts - feel free to explore this community!

Comment: @phani_yelugula Ive just implemented this, but when I click the button, the whole page content jumps to the left by about 10px. Any ideas why this is / how to avoid this happening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Do not do it.  I might want to run my car on monkey blood.  I have my reasons, but sometimes it's better to stick with using things the way they were designed even if it doesn't "absolutely perfectly" match the exact look you are driving for.

To back up my argument I submit the following.

- See how this image lacks the status bar at the bottom.  This link is using the `onclick="location.href"` model. (This is a real-life production example from my predecessor)  This can make users hesitant to click on the link, since they have no idea where it is taking them, for starters.

[image]

You are also making Search engine optimization more difficult IMO as well as making the debugging and reading of your code/HTML more complex.  A submit button should submit a form.  Why should you(the development community) try to create a non-standard UI?

Comment: Um, I'm guessing one takes us to the Tangible Department and the other to Customer Assistance. Most users don't even look at the status line (or even understand what it is). Developers do, but users don't. Users like buttons, but are distrustful of links (because links take them somewhere, buttons are just imperatives). Go to popular sites like Amazon and see the buttons.

Comment: Not an answer. Good points, but still not an answer to the question asked.

Answer (score 4):

For those who stumble upon this from a search (Google) and are trying to translate to .NET and MVC code. (as in my case)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RemoveLostRolls", "Process", FormMethod.Get)) {
     <input type="submit" value="Process" />
}
```

This will show a button labeled "Process" and take you to "/Process/RemoveLostRolls".
Without "FormMethod.Get" it worked, but was seen as a "post".

Answer (score 1):

I think that is your need.

```
a href="#" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();return false;"
```

Comment: That's not a button and doesn't answer the question.