# How to send a button in email sent?

Tags: java, email

In my application i am sending email to the new user , I want to send a button as well in the email , on when user click .he will be redirected to my website..

I have this right now

```
message.setSubject("TIE Account Created");
message.setText("Dear " + user.getFirstName() +" "+ user.getLastName()+" "
    + "\n\n  Your  Account created,"
    + "\n\n Please activate your account" 
    + " <a href=www.example.eu:8080/Project/#!"+ user.getToken()+" >"
    +" <button>Activate your Account</button> </a>"
    );
Transport.send(message);
```

Now what I am getting in email is the same code and no button, like this :

```
Dear user
Your Account created,
Please activate your account <a href=www.example.eu:8080/Project/#!d11qddnobot2665mjl20va87qh > <button>Activate your Account</button> </a>
```

Comment: Wasn't this asked a little while ago?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JAVA:send button in email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649812/javasend-button-in-email)

Comment: You can try to use [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/). Way much better than hardcoding html text.

Answer (score 3):

Most of email clients will likely discard the button tags in your email. So just use the well-styled "a" element. [Here](http://www.industrydive.com/blog/how-to-make-html-email-buttons-that-rock/) is an article with a good example.

**Update:**

Also it seems that you're sending email with plain text instead of html content. Please google for how to send html email with javamail API. [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm) is a nice example.