# Trying to use something like href on a <button> element

Tags: javascript, css, html

Im trying to add a href option to my `<button>` but its not working!
I use href to open other links in my `<li>` elements like this:

```
<li><a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">My Link</a></li>
```

But now with button, the button dont have the href option so Im trying with onclick method but its not working, like this:

```
<button class="btn" onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com'">
   <img  src="images/icon1.png" width="40" height="40"/>
   <span>My Link 1</span>
 </button>
```

Do you know how we can solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of 
[how to make a input type=button act like a hyperlink and redirect using a get request?]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303675/how-to-make-a-input-type-button-act-like-a-hyperlink-and-redirect-using-a-get-re

Comment: I didnt see that post, thank you very much!

Comment: @OzzC your code should work OK, if you tried it in a fiddle, of course it won't work because **Google does not allow itself to be loaded into a frame**, try another address like `http://www.bing.com` http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/yeZK2/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
   <button class="btn" onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com';">
      <img  src="images/icon1.png" width="40" height="40"/>
       <span>My Link 1</span>
    </button>
```