# Asp.net redirect with a ID

Tags: c#, asp.net

sorry if this post is simple to you.

I have one simple page in asp.net + C#, and have a multiple data in tables, each line of data table have a bottom. I need when a user clink one button redirect to order page with a id of data.

The page where the user will be redirected, must receive the id to make queries in the database.

My problem is don't have information about research this problem.

Bests

Comment: MVC, WebForm, Api? What are you using? What have you tried? "My problem is don't have information about research this problem." You just described what you're trying to accomplish. Should be enough to get you started.

Comment: How do you output the buttons? Can you [use this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303675/how-to-make-a-input-type-button-act-like-a-hyperlink-and-redirect-using-a-get-re)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple. It's called HTTP GET request with parameters. To do this, in a nutshell, follow

1. One page would list products and embed correct links to (step 2)
2. Another page would receive id and make queries to the database

If you search for `ASP.NET HTTP GET request with parameters` you'd find many tutorials. Also check out http://www.asp.net for getting started guides. There are several approaches in ASP.NET how you can do this. If you have nowhere to start, go here [Getting Started with ASP.NET MVC 5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started).