# Issue with implementing Modal using Button inside a link

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an existing MVC4 application, and need to implement a modal form.

I'm trying to implement this solution...

http://jsfiddle.net/kumarmuthaliar/GG9Sa/1/

This works just fine, but the example uses a link, and I need it to be a button.

I could try to style the link as a button, but there's a bunch of other buttons on the same form and it would need to look exactly like those, and I haven't found a good way to style the link exactly like the other buttons in every browser, since most of the button's default style properties aren't overridden.

I've tried wrapping the link around a button, like shown below...

```
<a href="#MathFactsModal"><button type="button">Continue</button></a>
```

This works fine in Chrome, but in IE11 when I'm testing the button shows up but doesn't do anything when I click it.  Again, the exact same code works fine in Chrome - pressing the button does pop the modal open, but doesn't work in IE.  Also, you get an HTML5 validation warning when a button is nested inside a link.

So, what can I do to make my link look exactly like all my other buttons?  Or is there some way I can implement this modal solution without using a link that directs to an anchor?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make an input type=button act like a hyperlink and redirect using a get request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303675/how-to-make-an-input-type-button-act-like-a-hyperlink-and-redirect-using-a-get-r)

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate of that.  The problem I have is that the modal solution I want to implement requires an anchor link.  I need a button that links to the anchor in the same way a normal anchor link does.  I don't want to redirect anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why your current example isn't working but there are plenty of examples in this stack overflow question/answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303675/how-to-make-an-input-type-button-act-like-a-hyperlink-and-redirect-using-a-get-r).

Comment: I need my button to go to an anchor on the same page.  Most of the answers on that question are submitting a form and redirecting, which won't work as I'm using MVC4 and there's already an outer form that does something different.  And the other answer suggests putting a button nested inside the link, but I already mentioned in my OP that this doesn't seem to work in IE...

Comment: Theres a few interesting options on there that aren't form based. For example simply adding a button with a javascript event of "window.location='#MathFactsModal'" - wouldn't this do what you're looking for?

Comment: Wow you're right, that works.  I didn't know window.location worked with an anchor - I thought it had to be a URL.  Shows how noob I am with web development.  Thanks.